# How to combine rows based off of duplicate values?

Tags: r, merge, sum, aggregate

Basically what we have is several columns as follows:

`Household ID`, `restaurantspend`, `groceryspend`, `foodtruckspend`

We have duplicate household ids because each spend is in its own individual column so an example of our data looks like this:

[image: example]

[data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QAc4.png)
We want to have the `Household ID` only have 1 row per id and combine the numerical values of the other column.

Comment: Please don't post [images of data](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and show us [what you have tried already](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Comment: give a minimal reproducible example, using dput() of your data or even pasting the output of head(). Try to clarify your question (what do you want as combine : a sum, a mean, ...), and try to look for answer because there is a lot about selecting and combining per group in SO

Answer (score 0):

```
aggdata = aggregate(mydata, by=list(mydata$HouseHoldID),Fun=sum)
```

I have created the above table and saved it as "Mydata". Run the above code. View the output "aggdata", you can see an extra column "Group.1" that's the group based on "HouseHoldID". You can ignore the second column "HouseHoldId" as the same information will be available in the column "Group.1".